# How do I get the most frequent word in a Map and it's corresponding frequency of occurrence using Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, multimap

I have a class `IndexEntry` which looks like this:

```
public class IndexEntry implements Comparable<IndexEntry>
{
    private String word;
    private int frequency;
    private int documentId;
    ...
    //Simple getters for all properties
    public int getFrequency()
    {
        return frequency;
    }
    ...
}
```

I am storing objects of this class in a Guava `SortedSetMultimap` (which allows for multiple values per key) where I am mapping a `String` word to some `IndexEntry`s. Behind the scenes, it maps each word to a `SortedSet<IndexEntry>`.

I am trying to implement a sort of indexed structure of words to documents and their occurrence frequencies inside the documents.

I know how to get the *count* of the most common word, but I can't seem to get the word itself.

Here is what I have to get the count of the most common term, where `entries` is the `SortedSetMultimap`, along with helper methods:

```
public int mostFrequentWordFrequency()
{
    return entries
            .keySet()
            .stream()
            .map(this::totalFrequencyOfWord)
            .max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(0);
}

public int totalFrequencyOfWord(String word)
{
    return getEntriesOfWord(word)
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(IndexEntry::getFrequency)
            .sum();
}

public SortedSet<IndexEntry> getEntriesOfWord(String word)
{
    return entries.get(word);
}
```

I am trying to learn Java 8 features because they seem really useful. However, I can't seem to get the stream working the way I want. I want to be able to have both the word and it's frequency at the end of the stream, but barring that, if I have the word, I can very easily get the total occurrences of that word.

Currently, I keep ending up with a `Stream<SortedSet<IndexEntry>>`, which I can't do anything with. I don't know how to get the most frequent word without the frequencies, but if I have the frequency, I can't seem to keep track of the corresponding word. I tried creating a `WordFrequencyPair` POJO class to store both, but then I just had a `Stream<SortedSet<WordFrequencyPair>>`, and I couldn't figure out how to map that into something useful.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it would be a better design to use the `documentId` as the key of the `TreeMultimap` rather than the `word`:

```
import com.google.common.collect.*;

public class Main {

    TreeMultimap<Integer, IndexEntry> entries = TreeMultimap.<Integer, IndexEntry>create(Ordering.arbitrary(), Ordering.natural().reverse());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Add elements to `entries`

        // Get the most frequent word in document #1
        String mostFrequentWord = entries.get(1).first().getWord();
    }

}

class IndexEntry implements Comparable<IndexEntry> {

    private String word;

    private int frequency;

    private int documentId;

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public int getDocumentId() {
        return documentId;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(IndexEntry i) {
        return Integer.compare(frequency, i.frequency);
    }

}
```

You can then implement the methods that you had before with the following:

```
public static int totalFrequencyOfWord(String word) {
    return entries.values()
                   .stream()
                   .filter(i -> word.equals(i.getWord()))
                   .mapToInt(IndexEntry::getFrequency)
                   .sum();
}

/**
 * This method iterates through the values of the {@link TreeMultimap},
 * searching for {@link IndexEntry} objects which have their {@code word}
 * field equal to the parameter, word.
 *
 * @param word
 *     The word to search for in every document.
 * @return
 *     A {@link List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>} where each {@link Pair<>}
 *     will hold the document's ID as its first element and the frequency
 *     of the word in the document as its second element.
 *
 * Note that the {@link Pair} object is defined in javafx.util.Pair
 */  
public static List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> totalWordUses(String word) {
    return entries.values()
                   .stream()
                   .filter(i -> word.equals(i.getWord()))
                   .map(i -> new Pair<>(i.getDocumentId(), i.getFrequency()))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: So, suppose that I needed to see all of the document ids that a given word was present in, along with the number of occurrences in that document. In your example, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I'll write up a method to do that and explain how it works

Comment: You're welcome!  And I've edited the post with the new method.  It returns a `List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>` holding the document ID and frequency of the specific word in the document.  It's basically a list of tuples.

Comment: Perfect! This will help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Native solution by JDK:

```
entries.keySet().stream()
     .collect(groupingBy(IndexEntry::getWord, summingInt(IndexEntry::getFrequency)))
     .values().stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(0L);
```

Or By [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
StreamEx.of(entries.keySet())
    .groupingBy(IndexEntry::getWord, summingInt(IndexEntry::getFrequency))
    .values().stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(0L);
```